# where is CEventThread source in android aosp

Tags: android, android-source

Reading android logcat I found quite a few `CEventThread` messages. But I can't find its source code in aosp by grepping CEventThread. Could anyone give me some hints to its source code? Thanks.

```
D/EVENT_THREAD(  158): void CEventThread::trig(uint16_t): in
D/EVENT_THREAD(  158): void CEventThread::trig(uint16_t): out
D/EVENT_THREAD(  158): void CEventThread::run() Do poll with timeout: -1
```

Comment: yes. running intel android.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think CEventThread is part of AOSP.

You probably are using non - nexus device and the source code is proprietary to the OEM